# react-native-ssl-pinning - The certificate for this server is invalid

Tags: react-native, ssl, http-post

Help me please

I am trying to make a request with react-native-ssl-pinning but get error (IOS 14.2):

> The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to
> a server that is pretending to be “https://...” which could put your
> confidential information at risk.

I copied the .cer certificate into xcode and do this:

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: body,
        pkPinning: true,
        disableAllSecurity: false,
        // your certificates array (needed only in android) ios will pick it automatically
        sslPinning: {
          certs: ['my_cer_file_without_extension'], // your certificates name (without extension)
        },
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          e_platform: 'mobile',
        },
      });
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be? Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this? getting the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

in iOS, make sure that you add the certificate to the bundle resources. Go to Build Phases > Copy bundle resources > Add the certificate.